how to use an android studio module inside another module
I am really new into this topic, I have a simple project that is an android studio template with some modifications, the project is a simple application with sidebar menu, the android studio uses fragments for this case, now I want to use a module from another project (https://github.com/yamin8000/Gauge) inside one of the fragments (Home) of the app, I imported the module and did some gradle changes so the project has two modules now, one is the default "app" module, and the second is the "Gauge" module from the source project, but I absolutely have no clue how to perform it, shall I import the module like this: "import (project(":Gauge"))" or what? can someone explain me in simple language so I can understand it, tnx
the project overall preview

I wrote an article about working on a multi library project in Android. It might be of help to you.

@tomerpacific
thanks for your very helpful information but the "workingLocally" shows unresolved reference when I try to use it in setting.gradle

Please provide all necessary code for a [mre] in the question itself. Links to code on external sites are not sufficient.

You have that import (project(:Gauge)) – it's not gonna work this way. Here is what you should do:

Go to your app's build.gradle and put this string to dependencies block, if it is not already there:

implementation project(:Gauge)

Run Gradle sync

Now, you can use classes and methods from Gauge module. Android Studio is smart enough and will provide you suggestions when you will start typing Gauge or something and will add needed imports automatically

actually I tried to use the module as     implementation("com.github.yamin8000.gauge:Gauge:1.0.3")
in the build.gradle file, but still I am struglling how to perform it

Well it should work that way. If you do this, then Gradle sync, you'll be able to import needed, of example import com.github.yamin8000.gauge.main.Gauge like in the example app here

yes that's right, it is working perfectly but I don't know where to implement the code, I want ot use it under Home, but home has HomeFragment and HomeViewModel under com/example/voltage/ui/home dir and also there is a res/layout/fragment_home.xml too, so which one is the main part of the Home I try to implement the code?

Well, we know to little about your setup to answer this question, unfortunately. But, since Gauge is composable function and you claim that you are using fragments, start from here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/compose-in-views

Step 1:
Locate your module from another project in settings.gradle.kts:
// below everything

include ':library:webRtc'
project(':library:webRtc').setProjectDir(new File(settingsDir, "../../Libraries/audiocall/webRtc"))

Step 2: add this module as dependency in app/build.gradle.kts file:
dependency {
    implementation(project(":library:webRTC"))
    // other dependenceis...
}


I don't know which template or instruction you follow to learn Android. Still, at this point, if you're just a beginner I don't think you need to physically copy another project into yours so you can use it (you don't need a multi-module project at this point, especially for adding a simple library to your project). I assume you want to use Gauge in your project, as demonstrated here you just need to add this line:
implementation("com.github.yamin8000.gauge:Gauge:1.0.3")  

to your app's build.gradle file and sync your grade, after that, you can use the Gauge and as others mentioned this is a Compose library and your project is using Views.
